# my sonarqube always said no code coverage for java

Tags: java, sonarqube

hi all i have build unit testing for controller, repository and Service but why in my sonarqube code coverage always give me code coverage only 0 percent. my question is how to make my percentage up ?

[image]

here what i was code in my testing

Comment: please post code as snippet and not as photo, take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube uses existing code coverage reports from [JaCoCo](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) (in the case of Java). Usually, you would set up the JaCoCo Maven plugin (or Gradle) to gather coverage info on test run and Sonarqube then loads this report.

See also the Sonarqube [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/) for info on setup. But if you are using Maven/Gradle, I believe Sonarqube is able to automatically pick up the correct file unless you have some special configuration.